# How to write on Read Only NFC Tag

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

I have locked a NFC tag using makeReadyOnly() using specific app and now I want to rewrite tag only from that specific app.

I have followed these documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef#makeReadOnly()

I know NFC bits are permanently locked and cant be reverted. I will appreciate any possible workaround or trick to get my job done. Like Retag does using id technique although I didn't apply this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a Tag that is readOnly to everything except your App then most Tags offer password protecting the write operation, BUT how to do this is usually specific to the make and model of the Tag's you are using.

So you don't specify the make and model of the Tag you are using it it hard to help in detail, just checkout the datasheet for your Tag.

This particular Tag is probably not writable to any more but some Tag's (Ones not NFC specification compliant), might not implement this readonly protection in hardware, so it might be possible to use low level API's to change other data on the card, bypassing the checks in the NDdef implementation - I've seen one Tag at least where this is possible.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Can you please mention that tag name and what is mean by not nfc compliant? Mention API reference for changing data?

Comment: Some Tags are certified/designed so that they comply with one of the NFC Forum Standard Type Tags. e.g. NXP 216 Tag is a "Fully comply to NFC Forum Type 2 Tag", others like NXP's Mifare Classic Tags don't comply to any NFC Forum Tag Type, but a lot of devices still support them in some fashion and can be made to support the NFC Forum higher level NDEF specification. I cannot remember the model name from NXP but it behaved like a Type 2 Tag but it came from the factory with the memory page used on a type 2 tag for the Capability container as empty and thus was not fully compliant.